# Mirror histogram, have code but worried its discarding data?

Tags: r, graph

So I'm trying to make my own mirrored histograms in R. An example of these can be seen here: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD7H7.jpg)

Similar to the example, I have two groups (diabetics and none-diabetics). There are a different number of observations in each group, something like 66 in one and 288 in the other. I found some example code of what I'm looking for, but when I run it I get the error:

```
Warning message:
Removed 222 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
```

The code I'm running is:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x) ) +
  # Top
  geom_histogram( aes(x = group1, y = ..density..), fill="#ABABAB" ) +
  geom_label( aes(x=4.5, y=0.25, label="variable1"), color="#69b3a2") +
  # Bottom
  geom_histogram( aes(x = group2, y = -..density..), fill= "#545454") +
  geom_label( aes(x=4.5, y=-0.25, label="variable2"), color="#404080") +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("value of x")

p
```

df is a dataframe of 2 columns, one for each group. The columns are of uneven length, the first is 288 and the second is 66. The columns are just named group1 and group2. 
I'm worried if the code is discarding valid measurements from the larger group I have, ie the first column, especially as the difference between 288 and 66 is 222.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in each row the data is not "paired", then don't store them like that. It is often inferred (by many R tools, even) that each value in a row of a `data.frame` is paired with the other values on that row, as if they are all different attributes or properties of the same "observation". In your case, the unevenness will result in either (1) lots of `NA` values starting warnings like that, or (2) lose data (less likely). I suggest it should be two columns, perhaps `group` (string, indicating diabetic or not) and `value` (some value).

Getting from your data to this data may not be hard, perhaps `tidyr::pivot_longer` or similar.

Here's how I would structure the data and use it:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  grp = sample(c("diabetic", "non-diabetic"), size=1000, replace=TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
dat$val <- ifelse(dat$grp == "diabetic", rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000, 2))
head(dat)
#            grp          val
# 1 non-diabetic  1.398617002
# 2 non-diabetic  1.864183863
# 3     diabetic -0.002456267
# 4 non-diabetic  2.831925015
# 5 non-diabetic  1.204940484
# 6 non-diabetic  2.340464612

ggplot(dat, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), fill = "gray", color = "black",
                 data = ~ subset(., grp == "diabetic")) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = -..density..), fill = "gray60", color = "black",
                 data = ~ subset(., grp != "diabetic")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image: ggplot2 mirrors histogram]

Comment: Thank you so much, great solution to my problem!